# Strange behavior when parsing adb shell output

Tags: android, bash, adb

I'm trying to figure out how to parse `adb shell` output from a bash script :

I have the following preset variables :

```
typeset adb=$(which adb)
typeset dos2unix="$(which tr) -d '\r'"
```

I want to clear the cache of all android apps matching a specific pattern, so here's what I do :

```
$adb shell pm list packages $applicationPattern | $dos2unix | cut -d: -f2 | while read package
do
    echo "=> Processing <$package> ..."
    $adb shell pm clear $package | $dos2unix
done
```

but here is the output I get knowing I have 3 package names matching the "bible" pattern :

```
$ ./adbClearAllApplicationsCache_AND_DATA.sh bible
=> Processing <com.biblehub.biblehubapp> ...
com.hagiostech.greekinterlinearbible
world.messianic.bible
Success
```

But if I redirect the `pm list` command in a variable it works :

```
typeset packageList=$($adb shell pm list packages $applicationPattern | $dos2unix | cut -d: -f2) && echo "=> packageList = <$packageList>"
for package in $packageList
do
    echo "=> Processing <$package> ..."
    $adb shell pm clear $package | $dos2unix
done
```

And here is the output :

```
$ ./adbClearAllApplicationsCache_AND_DATA.sh bible
=> packageList = <com.biblehub.biblehubapp
com.hagiostech.greekinterlinearbible
world.messianic.bible>
=> Processing <com.biblehub.biblehubapp> ...
Success
=> Processing <com.hagiostech.greekinterlinearbible> ...
Success
=> Processing <world.messianic.bible> ...
Success
```

I'd love to understand why and/or how to do it without having to use an intermediate variable.

EDIT 0 : @shellter Here's the exact output you need :

```
$ $adb shell pm list packages $applicationPattern | $dos2unix | cut -d: -f2
com.biblehub.biblehubapp
com.hagiostech.greekinterlinearbible
world.messianic.bible
```

And in hexadecimal :

```
$ $adb shell pm list packages $applicationPattern | $dos2unix | cut -d: -f2 | \od -c -tx1
0000000   c   o   m   .   b   i   b   l   e   h   u   b   .   b   i   b
         63  6f  6d  2e  62  69  62  6c  65  68  75  62  2e  62  69  62
0000020   l   e   h   u   b   a   p   p  \n   c   o   m   .   h   a   g
         6c  65  68  75  62  61  70  70  0a  63  6f  6d  2e  68  61  67
0000040   i   o   s   t   e   c   h   .   g   r   e   e   k   i   n   t
         69  6f  73  74  65  63  68  2e  67  72  65  65  6b  69  6e  74
0000060   e   r   l   i   n   e   a   r   b   i   b   l   e  \n   w   o
         65  72  6c  69  6e  65  61  72  62  69  62  6c  65  0a  77  6f
0000100   r   l   d   .   m   e   s   s   i   a   n   i   c   .   b   i
         72  6c  64  2e  6d  65  73  73  69  61  6e  69  63  2e  62  69
0000120   b   l   e  \n
         62  6c  65  0a
0000124
```

Comment: So we can test without the same environment, edit your Q to include exact (line-for-line) output of `$adb shell pm list packages $applicationPattern | $dos2unix | cut -d: -f2` . Good luck.

Comment: Interesting that using a variable solves the problem, it is usually the other way around (trying to use a variable, when you don't need one!;-)). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Added EDIT0 to give the output you need :)

Comment: @shellter Added the hexadecimal output of the command

Comment: busy now. Will look at this again. Thanks for the `od` output, rather amazing this is a problem. Good luck.

Comment: keep it simple: `adb shell "pm list packages $applicationPattern | cut -c9- | xargs pm clear"`

Comment: @AlexP. I also want to be able to see the progression of the clear operations, that's why I added a loop